# Как выполняются функции вызванные через указатель?

Tags: c++, c, указатели

Всем привет. Такой вопрос: если функция вызывается через указатель, то она выполняется точно так же как и обычный вызов функции, ну т.е. создается кадр стека, сохраняются значения регистров и т.п. ?

Я просто читал, что параметры по умолчанию не работают в случае вызова функции через указатель. Причина следующая:
"Параметры по умолчанию не будут работать с функциями, вызванными через указатели на функции. Параметры по умолчанию обрабатываются во время компиляции (т.е. вам нужно предоставить аргумент для параметра по умолчанию во время компиляции). Однако указатели на функции обрабатываются во время выполнения."

ссылка на ресурс: https://ravesli.com/urok-104-ukazateli-na-funktsii/

Не совсем понятно, что значит "во время компиляции" и "во время выполнения",  разве это не одно и то же?

Comment: Начните разбираться с последнего вопроса (что значит "во время компиляции" и "во время выполнения") и тогда поймете почему при вызове через указатель не возможно определить значения параметров по умолчанию))
На счет стека и регистров - это всё одинаково, а вот параметры по умолчанию, действительно, использовать не получится

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Такой вопрос: если функция вызывается через указатель, то она выполняется точно так же как и обычный вызов функции, ну т.е. создается кадр стека, сохраняются значения регистров и т.п.

Да. При обычном вызове он выполняется по сути через указатель — переходом к коду функции по определенному адресу.

> параметры по умолчанию не работают в случае вызова функции через указатель

Представим, что вы — компилятор... У вас есть

```
int f(int x = 2);
int g(int x = 3);
...
int (*func)(int);
...
// Длинные вычисления (возможно, в другом файле) и, наконец, вызов:

int x = func();
```

Еще раз — вы — компилятор. Какой аргумент вы должны вставить в этот вызов? 2 или 3? Причем это вы должны сделать прямо сейчас, во время компиляции! *Никакой иной информации, кроме той, что вы видите на экране, у вас нет*.

> что значит "во время компиляции" и "во время выполнения", разве это не одно и то же?

Вы едете отдыхать на море. Выезжая, вы должны решить, что вы берете с собой — зонтик от дождя, маску для ныряния или что-то там еще. Решаете вы это все дома. А вот что применять и как — будет понятно только на море. И если вы что-то с собой не возьмете, то там его уже будет негде взять.

Это так, очень натянутая аналогия. Компилятор разбирает ваш код и создает код, выполняемый процессором. И все неприятности он должен разрешить именно во время компиляции, во время выполнения ничего исправить уже нельзя. Вызов функции с параметром со значением по умолчанию компилятор при компиляции превращает в вызов с конкретным значением, а процессор просто выполняет все команды по вызову, даже не подозревая, что вы не указали аргумент. Тем более что никакого исходного кода и объявления функций в этот момент времени — во время выполнения скомпилированной программы — уже нет. Нет имен переменных, есть только адреса в памяти. Нет имен функций — тоже только адреса. Нет каких-нибудь циклов `for` — только организованные переходы по такому-то адресу, если значение в регистре имеет такое-то значение...